# On Demand TLS and Reverse Proxy Support for Custom Domains

Tags: nginx, dns, reverse-proxy, cname, caddy

I came into a situation today. Please share your expertise

I have a project (my-app.com) and one of the features is to generate a status page consisting of different endpoints.

**Current Workflow**

1. User login into the system
2. User creates a status page for one of his sites (e.g.google) and adds different endpoints and components to be included on that page.
3. System generates a link for a given status page.

> For Example. `my-app.com/status-page/google`

4. But the user may want to see this page in his custom domain.

> For Example. `status.google.com`

5. Since this is a custom domain, we need **on-demand TLS** functionality. For this feature, I used [Caddy](https://caddyserver.com/) and is working fine. Caddy is running on our subdomain `status.myserver.com` and user's custom domain `status.google.com` has a **CNAME** to our subdomain `status.myserver.com`
6. Besides on-demand TLS, I am also required to do reverse proxy as
   shown below.

> For Example. `status.google.com ->(CNAME)-> status.myserver.com ->(REVERSE_PROXY)-> my-app.com/status-page/google`

But Caddy supports only **protocol, host, and port** format for reverse proxy like `my-app.com` but my requirement is to support reverse proxy for custom page `my-app.com/status-page/google`. How can I achieve this? Is there a better alternative to Caddy or a workaround with Caddy?

[image: My Current Implementation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, since you can't use a path in a reverse-proxy upstream URL, you'd have to do rewrite the request to include the path first, before initiating the reverse-proxy.

> Additionally, upstream addresses cannot contain paths or query strings, as that would imply simultaneous rewriting the request while proxying, which behavior is not defined or supported. You may use the [rewrite](https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/directives/rewrite) directive should you need this.

So you should be able to use an internal caddy `rewrite` to add the `/status-page/google` path to every request. Then you can simply use `my-app.com` as your Caddy reverse-proxy upstream. This could look like this:

```
https:// {
    rewrite * /status-page/google{path}?{query}
    reverse_proxy http://my-app.com
}
```

You can find out more about all possible Caddy `reverse_proxy` upstream addresses you can use here: https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/directives/reverse_proxy#upstream-addresses

However, since you probably can't hard-code the name of the status page (`/status-page/google`) in your Caddyfile, you could set up a script (e.g. at `/status-page`) which takes a look at the requested URL, looks up the domain (e.g. `status.google.com`) in your database, and automatically outputs the correct status-page.

Comment: Static upstream addresses can take the form that contains only scheme and host/port. It cannot contain paths.

Comment: Oops, you're right! Updated the answer!